# Convert String into Map and replace Middle Value with '*'

Tags: java, hashmap, java-11

I have a below code, that working as mention below

Input
{306c6149db32a01a08acb4aebb87f76a8d83bc0d629c20653c9fcdd81767af0d=576100007700006}

output will in HashMap
306c6149db32a01a08acb4aebb87f76a8d83bc0d629c20653c9fcdd81767af0d -> 576100xxxxxx0006

Code

public static Map<String, String> maskCan(String value) {

```
Map<String, String> can = Arrays.stream(value.replaceAll("[{}]", " ").split(","))
        .map(s -> s.split("=", 2))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0].trim(), s -> s[1].trim()));

can.replaceAll((k, v) -> (isEmpty(v)) ? null : v.substring(0, 6) + new String(new char[v.length() - 10]).replaceAll("\0", "x")
        + v.substring(v.length() - 4));
return can;
```

}

1. convert string into Hash Map
2. replace all middle value from '*'

Want to achieve

Reduce a line of code because first we convert a String into map, thereafter replace some value then return a Map. is any way will do in single line

I need to optimise the above code. I am using JDK 11 for this one.

Comment: Optimize in what way?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis reduce a line of code because first we convert a String into map, thereafter replace some value then return a Map. is any way will do in single line?

Comment: A single line may look optimized, but it likely means the same to the JVM at runtime while being harder to understand and maintain. The number of lines of code is a bad metric to optimize. Rather use a separate method.